# Custom setting on a network printer

Tags: hp, network-printer

I´m setting up a HP Color Laserjet 4730mfp printer on our network and I was wondering if I could someow set it up with a custom configuration for each user. We want to set it up so that every jobs will be stored as a locked job and the user needs to walk to the printer, select the job and insert his pin. This is fairly easy to set up manually on the client but I want to set it up so that when the printer is installed they are configured like that and with a default pin 1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the Printer Properties under Printing defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with HP's Web JetAdmin software.

Comment: The JetAdmin software is certainly up for the job but since there are only 4 printers that I need to manage it is a bit of an overkill :)
But thanks for the tip